# Problem with video removeFromSuperview 

Tags: objective-c, ipad

```
    NSString *urlStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"clip" ofType:@"m4v"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr];
    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,320, 460);
    [viewController.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    [moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES]; 
    moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
    [moviePlayer setMovieControlMode:MPMovieControlModeHidden];
```

I am playing mp4 file i need to removeFromSuperview when movie is finished.... in notification. is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You need to add Observers to the notifications that the MPMoviePlayer sends (probably in your viewDidLoad):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(exitedFullscreen)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(finishedPlayback:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

then in your methods that are called when the notification fires:

```
- (void)finishedPlayback:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
}

-(void)exitedFullscreen 
{
    [self.moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperView];
}
```